# Functional derivative where the functional is not an integral

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, frechet-derivative

Let $\phi(f)=F(f(x_1),f'(x_2),...,f^{(n)}(x_{n+1}))$ be a functional defined on $C^n([a,b])$: here $F$ is a given (say) smooth function and $x_1,...,x_{n+1}$ are given points in $[a,b]$. What is the functional derivative of $\phi$? I'm asking this question since usual texts about functional derivatives deals with functionals given as an integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to calculate the functional derivative of a given functional is to use its basic definition, so let's recall it in the form  introduced (under some restrictive conditions) by Vito Volterra (for the references see [this  Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives), where the problem of definition of functional derivatives is extensively examined)
$$
\delta\phi(f,\eta)=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{\phi[f+\varepsilon \eta]-\phi[f]}{\varepsilon} = \bigg{[}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varepsilon}\phi[f+\varepsilon \eta]\bigg{]}_{\varepsilon = 0} \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where $\eta$ belongs to the same function space as $f$.
By applying definition \eqref{1} to the functional $\phi:C^n([a,b])\to\Bbb R$ defined as $$
f\mapsto F\big(f(x_1),f^\prime(x_2),\ldots,f^{(n)}(x_{n+1})\big).
$$
after calling the general arguments of the (sufficiently) smooth function $F:\Bbb R^{n+1}\to \Bbb R$ as $(y_0,\ldots,y_n)$ in order to avoid any confusion that may arise, we get
$$
\begin{split}
\delta\phi(f,\eta) & = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{\phi[f+\varepsilon \eta]-\phi[f]}{\varepsilon}\\
& = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{F\big(f(x_1)+\varepsilon \eta(x_1),\ldots,f^{(n)}(x_{n+1})+\varepsilon \eta^{(n)}(x_{n+1})\big)-F\big(f(x_1),,\ldots,f^{(n)}(x_{n+1})\big)}{\varepsilon}\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}F\big(f(x_1),f^\prime(x_2),\ldots,f^{(n)}(x_{n+1})\big)\eta^{(i-1)}(x_i)
\end{split}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$

**Notes**

- In order for $\phi$ to have a functional derivative, it is necessary and sufficient that at least $F\in C^1(\Bbb R^{n+1})$
- Like the original functional $\phi$, also $\delta\phi$ doesn't have an integral representation.
- **Edit**: as correctly noted by truebaran, the functional derivative of $\phi$ is *linear* in this case, therefore it is at least a Gâteaux derivative. If the functional derivative is both *linear and continuous*, then it is a Frechet derivative.
- As said earlier, in [this  Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives) several issues related to currently found presentations of functional derivatives are analyzed.

Comment: There are actually $n+1$ variables $y_i$ :) But I don't believe you evaluated correctly. You should be differentiating $f+\epsilon\eta$ for the various slots.

Comment: Ops @TedShifrin. Thank you! I’ll correct the post as soon as I’ll be at home

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I think I got it but let me just ensure myself that I got it correcty: so functional derivative is nothing more than just Gateux derivative which is generalization of the directional derivative.In the standard calculus among directional derivatives are special ones namely the partial derivatives (which correspond to vectors from canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$). A vector created out of these partial derivatives serves as the total derivative. Physicists pursue this picture to the infinite dimensional context and speak about $\frac{\delta \phi}{\delta f(x)}$..

Comment: .. which is ,,directional derivative in the direction of Dirac delta function (more correctly: distribution)''. The function $x \to \frac{\delta \phi}{\delta f(x)}$ should be though as $\frac{\delta \phi}{\delta f}$-the total (functional) derivative of $\phi$. All these is heuristic but work perfectly well for most functional one encounters in the calculus of variation (functional in the integral form) since one can plug delta distributions in these functionals (with the usual agreement about the meaning of integral of delta ,,functions''). This is also the reason why in most examples the ...

Comment: ... functional derivative is not in the integral form: the integral gets cancelled by the Dirac delta ,,function''. So in our example one cannot really evaluate ,,partial derivatives'' $\frac{\delta \phi}{\delta f(x)}$ since delta functions cannot be plugged into the formul for $\phi$ but I believe that still this functional should be Gateux differentiable. So much for the genral theory which I understood from your answer and a given link: however as pointed out by @Ted Shifrin the terms $\eta$ should also be differentiated

Comment: @truebaran the functional derivative, when it exists, is a Gâteaux derivative only when it is *linear*: this is true for the functional you are considering in your  question, but not always. In the link to the Mathoverflow Q&A I embedded in the above answer there is a concrete example where the functional derivative exists but is not linear (while however being $1$-homogeneous).

Comment: @truebaran, about the formalism used by physicists, yes, they seem to implicitly use something similar to $\eta(x)=\delta(x-x_o)$ (where $x_o$ is a reference coordinate, for example) and this in many cases can be made rigorous (but not always). And this could also be the reason why most of the examples of functional derivatives you've seen are not in integral form: however, as again I pointed out in the linked Q&A, there are functional derivatives that simply cannot be expressed as integrals respect to any singular measure (including the delta distribution which is also a Radon measure).

Comment: @truebaran (cont'd) If your functional derivative involves pointwise evaluation of derivatives then this can be assimilated to the derivative of order $>1$ of the $\delta$-distribution which however is not a measure, and this seems the case for your $\phi$: in this situation, plugging the Dirac delta inside the functional derivative cannot be made a rigorous procedure. Regarding the comment, see my answer to Ted below.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not sure of what you mean: to fix ideas, let's put $\mathbf y=(y_1,\ldots, y_n)=\big(f(x_1),\ldots, f^{(n)}(x_n)\Big)$ and $\mathbf h(\varepsilon)=(h_1,\ldots, h_n)=\big(\varepsilon\eta(x_1),\ldots,\varepsilon\eta^{(n)}(x_n)\big)$. Then $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{\phi[f+\varepsilon\eta]-\phi[f]}{\varepsilon} =\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \frac{F(\mathbf y+\mathbf h(\varepsilon))-F(\mathbf y)}{\varepsilon} $$ and this is the ordinary differential of $F$, however evaluated at properly chosen points.

Comment: To understand the general procedure, I'd rather apply the definition of taking $\frac d{d\epsilon} F(f+\epsilon\eta)\Big|_{\epsilon=0}$ where $\eta$ is itself a perturbation of the function $f$. The functional here does not read in numbers, it reads in functions, so I'd rather feed it the function $f+\epsilon\eta$ and see what it spits out. The second argument, for example, should be $(f+\epsilon\eta)'(x_2)$. What you wrote here is, of course, correct, because derivatives and evaluation are linear. But the method applies totally generally.

Comment: To summarize: the final formula in the answer is correct provided one replaces $\eta(x_i)$ with $\eta^{(i-1)}(x_i)$

Comment: @truebaran Typo removed. Thanx to you and to Ted Shifrin for pointing out this slip.